# "Command line server for IE Driver has stopped working" error while executing tests with Selenium, IEDriverServer through Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I have been getting this series of intermittent failures with IEWebDriver:

Firstly a test fails and is not able to close the driver with using the .quit() method. I think this first failure is because IEDriver bombs.

I get a dialog box with:

```
Command line server for IE Driver has stopped working
```

After the first failure, IEDriver opens IE but when you try and perform an action on an object in a page you get the SocketTimeoutException. Interestingly it takes 3hours to fail with this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z' System info: host: 'WORKSTATION-3', ip: '172.26.50.248', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

How do I stop IEDriver from bombing and if I can't how do I prevent it from stopping the next test from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Command line server for IE Driver has stopped working
.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z' System info: host: 'WORKSTATION-3', ip: '172.26.50.248', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowsing Session* i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.12.0** of *2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z* which is a bit older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_92** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.12.0* and *JDK v8u92*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  current [**IEDriverServer v3.14.0.0**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) level.

  > **Note**: As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync you must use both the binaries from the same release.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.